# Swift 3.1 macos: Cant convert String to URL, Umlaute-Encoding

Tags: swift, macos, url-encoding

I read a lot about converting and encoding now, tho im struggling to make things work:
I want to convert a String containing Umlaute (such as ü,ä,ö) to URL, to execute removeItem(at: URL). Working perfectly fine without Umlaute.

```
pfadraus = "/Users/mdoe/Downloads/Test3 üKopie" 
let uhk = "file://\(pfadraus.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))"
let uhk2 = URL(string: uhk)!
```

Always returns nil, I suspect some encoding should be done, tho I struggle to set that up as well. As said, in the end

```
let löschen = try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: uhk2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to escape any special characters if you use the [dedicated method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780183-init) to convert a file path to an URL:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

But note that there is a [removeItem(atPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1408573-removeitem) method as well, so you don't need a conversion to an `URL`
just for this purpose.

Comment: I agree. Thing is, I loaded only the path of a file in String format with OpenPanel.

Comment: Quite new to swift and coding, tho the program has become somewhat large, is there a method to do as I wanted or shall I rewrite the OpenPanel-Part...?

Comment: @pikkuez: Sorry, I don't get what you are asking. I am suggesting that you replace your `let uhk2 = URL(string: uhk)!` by `let uhk2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: pfadraus)`

Comment: Sweet, now I get it, it worked, thank you very much!